# Getting value of virtual attribute method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get the value of a virtual attribute on my model, is there another way to get the value? I need to pass in a string into the hash to retrieve the value...

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  def full_address
    "#{address1}, #{city}, #{postcode}"
  end
end
```

Then trying to access the **value** of full address, like so:

```
att_name = 'full_address'
property[att_name]
```

The last line does not seem to work for me. property is an instance of Property.

Comment: Try `att_name = full_address`(*without quotes*)

Comment: What is `instruction`? An instance of `Property`?

Comment: @DeepakMahakale yes it is, updated just so there is no confusion. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

As Pavan mentioned in the comment, I will try to explain a bit more of what's going on there.

`att_name = 'full_address'`, here you are assigning a string to the att_name, **but you intend to call the function full_address**. *So call the function by removing the ' ' around full_address*

your code becomes `att_name = full_address`

Answer (score 2):

As I said, you should do `att_name = full_address` instead of `att_name = 'full_address'`.

when you do `att_name = 'full_address'` it assigns a value to `att_name` as `full_address`, since you defined it as a string.

Comment: is there anyway to call the function by passing in a string, see the att_name is set dynamically via a parameter, in most cases I am actually calling a attribute e.g. address1, city, postcode. However I have defined a function called full_address which I wanted to call in this particular case, let me know if you want me to clarify this further...

Comment: @Haroon I didn't understood what do you mean by passing a string. You can always return a dynamic value from `full_address` for different property instances. Also call it directly like `property.full_address`